# What is purpose of on-select-page (page) Pagination Settings in angular UI Bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

As per mentioned in the document angular ui bootstrap [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). I used it as following but it does not seems to work

```
<pagination 
            items-per-page="pagesize" 
            total-items="totalItems" 
            page="currentPage" 
            max-size="maxSize" 
            class="pagination-sm" 
            boundary-links="true" 
        rotate="false" 
        num-pages="numPages"
        on-select-page="refreshList"
>
</pagination>
```

and in my Controller added

```
$scope.refreshList = function(page){
    console.log(page);
    $scope.userlist();
}
```

But it does working. Function is not getting called. Where am I doing mistake?

Answer (score 3):

in version 0.11.0 UI bootstrap pagination, the 'page' and 'onSelectPage' were replaced with ng-model for page and ng-change for on-select-page. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/d65901cff87ab895df997a803222f94ac223e9d3)

Answer (score 0):

Its an expression so you need:  `refreshList()`

---

```
<pagination 
        items-per-page="pagesize" 
        total-items="totalItems" 
        page="currentPage" 
        max-size="maxSize" 
        class="pagination-sm" 
        boundary-links="true" 
    rotate="false" 
    num-pages="numPages"
    on-select-page="refreshList()">
</pagination>
```